# Angular : Cannot locate two p-col-6 side by side in PrimeNG FlexGrid

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, primeng

I use [Flex Grid](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/flexgrid) in my Angular7 project but although the behavior is normal in the first situation, and I can locate two p-col-6 side by side, I cannot make them side by side after moving them in p-col-12. Here is the problem:

***#status 1:***

```
<style>
    .p-grid {
        border: 2px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .p-col-6 {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 2px solid green;
        flex: 1 0 50%; 
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
</style>

<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col-6">
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6">
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6">
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

There is no problem here. But when using this as shown below the problem occurs:

***#status 2:***

```
<style>
    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .p-grid {
        border: 2px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .p-col-6 {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 2px solid green;
        flex: 1 0 50%; 
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        max-width: 50%;
    }

    .p-col-12 {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 2px solid green;
        flex: 1 0 100%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col-12">
        <div class="p-col-12">12</div>

    </div>

    <div class="p-col-12">
        <div class="p-col-12">12</div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-12">
        <div class="p-col-6">
            6
        </div>
        <div class="p-col-6">
            6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But cannot make col-6's side by side even if changing width properties. ANy idea?

[image]

Comment: @OptimumCreative Any reply please?

Comment: You could simply add the .p-grid class to the div.p-col-12 that holds your two .p-col-6 elements

Comment: @DerAlex Many thanks Alex, you rock!.. I copied **p-grid** to **.p-grid .p-col-12** and now it is working :) On the other hand, **what about giving the marging between two p-col-6 globally?** I do not want to add style property to the each p-col-6 divs and looking a better solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the nesting you've added causes `.p-col-6` to no longer be a child of the flexbox parent, `.p-grid`. Instead, `.p-col-6` is a block level element, and will not align side-by-side as would typical row-directional flex children.

```html
<div class="p-grid">                   /* <-- flexbox  parent */
    <div class="p-col-12">             /* <-- flexbox  child */
        <div class="p-col-12">12</div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-12">             /* <-- flexbox  child */
        <div class="p-col-6">          /* <-- NOT a flexbox child */
            6
        </div>
        …
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy... On the other hand, what about giving the marging between two p-col-6 globally? I do not want to add style property to the each p-col-6 divs and looking a better solution. Any idea?

Comment: @Willys What do you mean you don't want to add `style property`? Do you mean that you don't want to add another class name?

Comment: I mean that **<div class="p-col-6" style="margin-right: 5px;"> 6 </div>** for each p-col-6 element but I think I have to do so. **BUT** in this case the second p-col-6 wraps and goes below to the first p-col-6. What should I do in order to fix this problem? I simply want to set margin and make space between two p-col-6 divs.

Comment: @Willys I illustrated above why you're having the problem. If you leave the `HTML` the way it is, you will need to make `.p-col12 { display: flex; }` to fix your problem.

Comment: It does not make any send and after making `.p-col12 { display: flex; }` and adding `margin-right: 5px;` the second p-col-6 goes below the first one. But when decreasing width property of p-col-6 to %45 it may be ok. However it will not be good when screen resizing as it causes gap increasing  between divs.

Comment: Any other  solution?

Comment: @Willys No other solution. This is how flexbox works.